# AS2 push to array outside of clip does nothing

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-2

was wondering if someone could show me what I'm doing wrong here.

I have some old AS2 flash code I'm trying to get working.

First I create a few arrays in frame 1 of the main timeline like so-

```
var typeArr:Array = new Array();

for (var i:Number = 1; i < 5; i++) 
{
    _root.typeArr[i] = "data goes here";
}
```

Then I have a movieclip dynamically attached on the main stage that when clicked appends one of the arrays we created by pushing the string 'foo' to it-

```
stop();

_root.myType=3;//this can be any of our array numbers

this.onPress=function(){

    var foo:String="test";

    _root.typeArr[_root.myType].push(foo);

    trace(_root.typeArr[_root.myType]);

}
```

Where `_root.typeArr[_root.myType]` is the array name and number `_root.typeArr3`, but pushing the data does not work and returns nothing.

However, if I test it directly using-

```
_root.typeArr[_root.myType]=foo;
```

It will store the data once (`_root.typeArr3=test`), so I can't see why it won't push to that array as multiple elements each time like- "test,test,test"

It's driving me crazy.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_root.typeArr[_root.myType]` is equal to `"data goes here"` so you are pushing string to a string, which doesn't work.

If you would like to append the new string, you should do something like:

```
_root.typeArr[_root.myType]+=foo;
```

and you will get: `data goes heretest`

If you have different data structure instead of "data goes here" the key may lie in the format of this data.

Comment: "+=foo" does append the data, but you made me think with "you are pushing string to a string, which doesn't work." so I changed the format to  _root.typeArr[i] = ["data goes here"];  which lets ".push" append as array elements in case other people have this same problem.

Comment: I am glad! If that answers your question you can maybe mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var typeArr:Array = new Array();

    // 'i' must start from 0 because the first element is typeArr[0]
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < 5; i++)  
    {
        typeArr[i] = i;
        // trace(typeArr[i]); // 0,1,2,3,4
    }

    // trace(typeArr); // 0,1,2,3,4

    myType = 3;

    bt.onPress = function()
    {
        var foo:String = "test";
        // push method puts the element at the end of your array
        // typeArr.push(foo); 
        // trace(typeArr); // 0,1,2,3,4,test

        // splice method replace the 4e element (index 3) of your array
        typeArr.splice(myType, 1, foo);
        trace(typeArr); // 0,1,2,test,4
    }
```